# PHP Pthreads - using mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pthreads

I'm trying to utilize pthreads for the first time in my web application.  I have pthreads working for simple test cases, but am having trouble getting mysql queries within pthreads to work.  Here's my php file:

```
class SqlThread extends Thread
{
    private $dbc;
    public $log;
    public $return;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->dbc = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "rootpassword", "my_database");

        $this->log = "<br>(".__LINE__.") construct finished.";
    }

    //gets called when thread is started
    public function run(){
        $val = $this->testSqlCall();

        $this->log .= "<br>(".__LINE__.") testSqlCall() has finished";

        $this->return = $val;
    }

    /**
     * testing sql queries
     */
    function testSqlCall(){

        $sql = "SELECT *
                FROM client_detail";

        $this->log .= "<br>(".__LINE__.") testSqlCall() - sql: ".$sql;

        $r= @mysqli_query($this->dbc,$sql);
        $num = mysqli_affected_rows($this->dbc);

        $this->log .= "<br>(".__LINE__.") testSqlCall() - total number of returned rows: ".$num;

        return $num;

    }
}

/**
 * threaded test
 */
$thread = new SqlThread();
$thread->start();
$thread->join();

echo "<br><br><br>thread return value:";
var_dump($thread->return);
echo $thread->log;

/**
 * same test, but not threaded
 */

$dbc = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "rootpassword", "my_database");
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM client_detail";
$r = @mysqli_query($dbc,$sql);
$num = mysqli_affected_rows($dbc);
echo "<br><br> --- non-threaded return value: $num";
```

and here's what it returns:

```
thread return value:

null


(12) construct finished.
(32) testSqlCall() - sql: SELECT * FROM client_detail
(37) testSqlCall() - total number of returned rows:
(19) testSqlCall() has finished

--- non-threaded return value: 39276
```

As you can see, the mysqli query within the SqlThread returns nothing, while the exact same query outside the SqlThread class returns what I would expect.

Any Ideas? Has anyone gotten sql queries within php threads to work?

Comment: You need to make the connection inside the thread. Instantiating it outside would make each thread use the same connection, which is not recommended if not wrong at all, the is also true in any multi-threading architecture. I first discovered this when I was doing multi-threaded database querying in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the mysqli object is unsuitable for use in multiple threads, you want to create an instance of MySQLi for each thread you start, so each thread has a unique connection.

```
<?php
define("SQLHOST", "localhost");
define("SQLUSER", "root");
define("SQLPASS", "");
define("SQLDB",   "test");
define("SQLPORT", 3306);
define("SQLSOCK", "/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock");

class Mine extends Thread {
    public function run() {
        try {
            $my = new mysqli(SQLHOST, SQLUSER, SQLPASS, SQLDB, SQLPORT, SQLSOCK);
            if ($my) {
                $result = $my->query("SHOW DATABASES;");

                if (is_object($result)) {
                    while (($row = $result->fetch_assoc())) {
                        var_dump($row);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception $ex) {
            var_dump($ex);
        }
    }
}

$mine = new Mine();
$mine->start();
?>
```

Yields

```
array(1) {
  ["Database"]=>
  string(18) "information_schema"
}
array(1) {
  ["Database"]=>
  string(5) "mysql"
}
array(1) {
  ["Database"]=>
  string(18) "performance_schema"
}
array(1) {
  ["Database"]=>
  string(4) "test"
}
```

Note that, the MySQLi object is never stored in the Threads object scope, because you should only store in the object scope that which you intend to share, and since you cannot share a MySQLi connection, it is best to manipulate it in the method scope.

There are many examples on github, including an SQLWorker example, you should read them all.

Further reading: https://gist.github.com/krakjoe/6437782