# php pthreads cannot run mysqli query within synchronized block?

Tags: php, mysqli, pthreads

I'am trying to update database witin synchronized block:

```
$this->mysqli_obj = CreateMysqli($DB ['host'], $DB ['user'], $DB ['password'], $DB ['database']);
if ($this->mysqli_obj == FALSE) {
    $error_info = sprintf("('%d') %s ", mysqli_connect_errno(), mysqli_connect_error());
    error_msg("MySQL connection error!", $error_info);
    return;
}

...


$this->synchronized(function(){ 

        ...

        SetProcessed($this->mysqli_obj, $DB ['worker_table'], $current, $this->step_two);
        SetGoodProcessed($mysqli_obj, $DB ['worker_table'], $valid, $this->step_two);

        echo "progress: " . $percent . " percent ($current of $data_size, valid: $valid) \n";
        echo "time: " . $t . "\n";

        ...
 });
```

But it doesnt update anything and log is full of errors like this:

```
[05-May-2016 18:00:50 UTC] PHP   4. var_dump() C:\xampp\htdocs\w\functions\thread_class.php:287
[05-May-2016 18:00:50 UTC] PHP   4. var_dump() C:\xampp\htdocs\w\functions\thread_class.php:287
[05-May-2016 18:00:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  var_dump(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\w\functions\thread_class.php on line 287
[05-May-2016 18:00:50 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[05-May-2016 18:00:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  var_dump(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\w\functions\thread_class.php on line 287
```

Why is this happening and how to resolve that?
I already have one connection per thread. Looks like mysqli object doesn't creating at all and contains NULL for some reason.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Pthreads - using mysqli](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22051049/php-pthreads-using-mysqli)

Comment: Short answer: Make one connection per thread.

Comment: @MattS I have one connection, it creating upon run()

Comment: SetGoodProcessed($mysqli_obj, ... $this->mysqli_obj ?

Comment: Also, which line is 287?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte, this one: var_dump($this->mysqli_obj)

Comment: Ok, but is this line in your synchronized block? Are your $DB var correct? If you put this var_dump right above the connector, it works?

Comment: $DB is correct and yes, the line in sync block. What exaclty i need to put in var_dump above connector?

Comment: Do not store mysqli objects as members of threaded objects, they are non-standard objects that require resources to work, keep them in class static (thread local for pthreads) scope somewhere ...

Comment: @JoeWatkins, thanks, got it.